# Change display settings with a service

Tags: teamcity, virtual-machine, resolution, headless, testcomplete

We are using TeamCity to start our tests. The TeamCity Agent is running as a service on a master VM running Windows Server 2012, an headless machine (manage by Hyper-V).

Right now, `Get-DisplayResolution` returns 1024X728. And when trying to change the display resolution with `Set-DisplayResolution`, it returns:
`T h e   s e t t i n g s   p a s s e d   i n   c o u l d   n o t   b e   a p p l i e d   t o   t h e   g r a p h i c s   d e v i c e .`

It seems that this machine is using the Basic Display Adapater driver of Microsoft (because there is no real display) and this driver fixes the resolution to 1024x768 (virtual resolution). 
But to perform our tests we would like to have a resolution of 1920x1080.
We are not performing our UI Tests directly on this machine but TestComplete will create different RDP connection on slave machines to start the UI Tests. These RDP connections will use the resolution of the master. This is why we want a better resolution on our master where the TeamCity agent is located.

Is there a way to change this resolution maybe with Hyper-V or is it possible to change the display settings through TeamCity with a powershell script or an other way ?

Thanks for your answers,

Camille